# LINQ - Group by Year and Month

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to write a linq query to group data from a datatable by year\month.

I've managed to group by one or the other but not both...

```
       Dim q = From p As DataRow In DTCalls.Rows _
                Group By Year = p("DATE").Year _
                Into CALLS = Count(p("CALL_ID")) _
                Select Year, CALLS
```

How do I group\order by year THEN month within the same query?

Source data:

```
DATE                    CALL_ID
2012-05-01 23:52:44   6587
2012-02-03 09:17:41   6562
2012-05-01 06:32:41   6565
2012-02-03 12:47:41   6565
2011-05-31 08:37:41   6511
```

Expected output:

```
DATE       COUNT
2011-05      1
2012-02      2
2012-05      2
```

Comment: In your example, you could simply group by date. You should show an example with two dates in the same year/month.

Comment: Sorry, example data was wrong. (updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by an anonymous type of two properties(year+month). You also need to apply the `Key` keyword in VB.NET.

[Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

```
Dim dateGroups =
    From row In table
    Let year = row.Field(Of Date)("DATE").Year
    Let month = row.Field(Of Date)("DATE").Month
    Group row By YearMonth = New With {
        Key .year = year,
        Key .month = month
    } Into DateGroup = Group
    Order By YearMonth.year, YearMonth.month

For Each grp In dateGroups
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}-{1} Count:{2}",
                      grp.YearMonth.year,
                      grp.YearMonth.month,
                      grp.DateGroup.Count())
Next
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong. There are two entries for march 2012 and one for march 2011.

Comment: Meanwhile OP has edited the question to provide better sample data. However, the answer should work anyway. (edited it to provide the correct order)

Comment: Great :) I was testing your first edit with dateGroups.ToList() to bind to a datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an anonymous type containing the two values or you can use a tuple:

```
Group By Tuple.Create(p("DATE").Year, p("DATE").Month)
```